# Java Selenium-webdriver: Enter the text into the text area

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-grid

Pic is attached for more detail please follow::![I want to enter the text in the text area: mentioned in photo][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sai92.png I want to enter the text into text area but error is occur that element is not found. I have tried with X path, name and id but couldn't execute this code and want to play with other elements appeared on the page for the testing purpose but nothing!!! i don't know that it can be handle with java-executor or switch window (pop up).below mention is java code. How to handle this situation please help with full detail.

Java code:

```
@Test   
public void CreteLead() throws InterruptedException 
{
    WebElement _loginName = 
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty("username")));

    _loginName.sendKeys(OR.getProperty("loginId"));

    WebElement _password = 
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty("password")));
            _password.sendKeys(OR.getProperty("loginPassword"));
    WebElement _login = 
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty("login")));

    _login.click(); 
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    WebElement _New = 
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty("New")));

    _New.click();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("btnCreateCustomer")).click();
```

HTML code:

```
<table class="tbl_top_align" width="100%" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <tr>
    <tr>
    <tr id="trBranch">
    <tr id="trAssign">
      <td> Assign To*: </td>
      <td>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="font-weight: normal !important;">
                <div 
                  id="ctl00_CPHPageContents_ctl00_CPHPageContents_ddlAssignedToPanel" 
                  class="RadAjaxPanel" style="display: block;"
                >
                  <span id="RequiredFieldValidator1" 
                    class="error_message" style="display:none;"
                  >* missing</span>
              </td>
              <td style="vertical-align: middle !important;">
              <td style="vertical-align: middle !important;"> Referral </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 4px 0 5px;"> Follow-up on: </td>
        <td style="padding: 4px 0 5px;">
          <a id="btnFollowUp" 
            href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$CPHPageContents$btnFollowUp','')"
          >Not Scheduled</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> Account: </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ctl00_CPHPageContents_txtAccount_wrapper" 
            class="riSingle RadInput RadInput_Default" style="width: 160px;">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> Value: </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ctl00_CPHPageContents_txtAccountValue_wrapper" 
            class="riSingle RadInput RadInput_Default" style="width: 125px;">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Description*:</td>
        <td>
          <textarea id="txtInstructions" class="schedule_notes" 
            style="height: 95px; width: 294px !important;" cols="20" rows="2"
            name="ctl00$CPHPageContents$txtInstructions"
          />
          <span id="RequiredFieldValidator2" class="error_message" 
            style="display:none;">* missing</span>
        </td>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="action_buttons">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

I had faced a similar issue with **textarea**, if you can **sendkeys** to the **previous input field**, just use **TAB** to move to next field (textarea) and enter text, it worked for me

```
driver.findElement(By.id("id_of_previous_input_field")).sendKeys(Keys.TAB,"This text will appear in textarea");
```

Comment: More advanced snippet if textarea needs to be cleared before: 
`webdriver.findElement(<locator of previous element>).sendKeys(Keys.TAB, Keys.chord(Keys.COMMAND, "a"), "This text will replace text in textarea");`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you click on 'new' button it opens a new popup window where you want to input your text. In that case you need to switch to this window first using something like:

> switchTo().window(handle)

And of course the problem is to find the handler. After you're on the popup window you can search for elements and use them.
[Here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/selenium-users/GYuouMBkrFU/bZe3W2SM-0UJ) you have useful thread about this issue with some explanation.

Comment: Now i have this code but Unable to locate element and show the windows id. winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandles();
  itrate=winHandleBefore.iterator();
  win=itrate.next();
  System.out.println("pop up"+win);
  driver.switchTo().window(win);
  
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div[1]/form/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/textarea")).sendKeys("test");

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with textarea too, I simply did this :

```
element = bw.find_element_by_class_name("XXX")
element.click() 
element = bw.find_element_by_class_name("XXX")
element.send_keys("Your text")
```

And it works ;)

Answer (score -1):

In your test method first you need to Save the WindowHandle of Parent Browser Window as follows.

```
String parentWindowId = driver.getWindowHandle(); // This should be the first line in your test method
```

After the code for clicking the "New" button (which opens the popup window) enter the following code.

```
Set<String> allOpenedWindows = driver.getWindowHandles();
        if(!allOpenedWindows.isEmpty()) {
        for (String windowId : allOpenedWindows) {
            driver.switchTo().window(windowId);

                if(driver.getPageSource().contains("Description")) //"Description" is the name of the label of your text area
                {
                    try{                    
                    WebElement textArea= driver.findElement(By.id("txtInstructions"));
                    textArea.sendKeys("Enter the text here");
                    break;

                }catch(NoSuchWindowException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }
                }
        }
```

Comment: there is no label in my html.



<td>                     Description*:                 </td>
<td>
<textarea id="txtInstructions" class="schedule_notes" style="height: 95px; width: 294px !important;" cols="20" rows="2" name="ctl00$CPHPageContents$txtInstructions"/>
<span id="RequiredFieldValidator2" class="error_message" style="display:none;">* missing</span>
</td>